# How to convert between 2 type aliases in python?

Tags: python, python-typing, pyright

I am trying to do the following in python:

```
import typing

TypeA = str

TypeB = typing.Union[typing.List[str], typing.List[int], int, str]

TypeC = typing.Dict[str, TypeB]

def funcA(arg1: TypeC):
    var1: typing.List[TypeA] = arg1["random_key"] # static typechecker i.e. pyright is not allowing this
```

How to make the typechecker i.e. pyright allow this assignment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use the `typing.cast` function to say "trust me, I know what I'm doing."

```
var1: typing.List[TypeA] = cast(typing.List[TypeA], .....)
```

And by the way, if you're using ≥3.9, you can just use `list` rather than `typing.List`.